# Getting error 101 at the time of voice calling method agoraEngine.registerEventHandler

Tags: react-native, agora.io, agora, agora-implementation

```
agoraEngineRef.current = createAgoraRtcEngine();
const agoraEngine = agoraEngineRef.current;
agoraEngine.initialize({
  appId: appId,
});

agoraEngine.registerEventHandler({
  onError: (err, msg) => {
    console.log("ERROR", err);
    console.log("msg", msg);
  },
});
```

While implementing Agora voice calling, when I call `registerEventHandler` in this method, I am getting error 101.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [error code list for Agora 3](https://docs.agora.io/en/3.x/voice-calling/reference/error-codes?platform=android), error 101 is invalid app id. So you should probably check if your `appId` is valid or not.